# Finding Average amount in excel for two values

Tags: excel

[image]I have a question regarding an excel sheet. I'm trying to find how many times something occurs on a specific date. For example:

```
Date                    User
1/1/2014 0:00           Michael Albanese
1/1/2014 0:00           Linus Nienstadt
1/1/2014 0:01           Omar Albanese
```

I want to find how many times Michael Albanese occurred in 2014

I've tried the following, but it returns an error.

```
=COUNTIFS(F2:F482240,"=Michael Albanese",E2:E482240,"=1/1/2014")
```

... it then says one, but there's at least three

Comment: I've tried that, but it returns an error.    =COUNTIFS(F2:F482240,"=Michael Albanese",E2:E482240,"=1/1/2014") it then says one, but there's at least three

Comment: are you looking at a discrete number of rows of data, or are you doing it for the entire column minus the header row in column 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR($A$2:$A$4)=2014)*($B$2:$B$4="Michael Albanese"))
```

If your dates are text that looks like dates then use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(2014,$A$2:$A$4)))*($B$2:$B$4="Michael Albanese"))
```

Comment: @Ashley then I would guess that your dates are not actual dates but text that looks like dates.

Comment: Would I use the same concept for 3 criteria?  For example, I want to find how many times in 2014 a particular user voted yes

Comment: Yes just multiply another TRUE/FALSE statement.

Comment: Hi, I tried taking it a step further and applying it to a full date, but I get an error                                                                                                                                =SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(1-Jan-2014,E:E)))*(F:F="Michael Albanese"))                                                                                                          it only says 1, but there's at least 10                                                        I've tried everything I can think of

Comment: You are comparing text strings.  So `=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1/1/2014",E:E)))*(F:F="Michael Albanese")).  The string you are trying to find needs to be exactly like the string you are look at.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108309/discussion-between-ashley-and-scott-craner).

Answer (score 1):

The [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) may be more efficient than the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) in this case.

```
=COUNTIFS(F:F, "Michael Albanese", E:E,">="&DATE(2014, 1, 1), E:E,"<"&DATE(2015, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(L2:L4)=2014)*(M2:M4="Michael Albanese"))
```

L2:L4 is your date stored in an Excel date serial format but can be formatted as text.

M2:M4 is your list of names

If your date time is stored as text you could try

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MID(L2:L4,FIND(" ",L2:L4)-4,4)*1=2014)*(M2:M4="Michael Albanese"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Findwindow is correct.  Here is a quick example.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,"<1/1/2015",A2:A10,">12/31/2013",B2:B10,"=Michael Albanese")
```

Comment: fwiw, this would also count `12/31/2013 08:00`.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the timestamp when I looked at this the first time.